# I need to open an Usercontrol in the main Window from another Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

Basically I have this Usercontrol, which is a main menu, with a new game button, a load button, and a setting button. 
I need this to open when I start it up, but more importantly when hit new game button I need the main menu to be replaced with another usercontrol. 
I have been trying and look up stuff for hours and have not worked out how to yet, so I hope someone can tell me what I have been doing wrong. Here is my current code.

I've still very much a beginner at programming and using this as a way to get bigger, so sorry if I seem slow.

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainInterfaceViewModel}">
        <local:MainInterface/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Character_CreationViewModel}">
        <local:Character_Creation/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Pokemorph Island;component/images/cover1.jpg"/>
</Window.Background>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="535*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="36*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="307*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DockPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ContentControl x:Name="FullScreen" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ContentControl x:Name="User" />
    </DockPanel>
    <Button Content="&gt;&gt;&gt;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Change_Image_UP" Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}" Margin="66,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51" Height="31" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Rockwell Extra Bold" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="&lt;&lt;&lt;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Change_Image_Down" Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51" Height="31" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Rockwell Extra Bold" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="Image Source" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Image_Source" Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}" Margin="431,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="84" Height="31" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="PATREON" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Patreon_Link" Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}" Margin="520,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="84" Height="31" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="Button" Margin="0,507,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding MainCommand}"/>
    <Button Content="Button" Margin="134,507,584,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding CharCreaCommand}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>


</Grid>
```

MainWindow Code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int cover = 1;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new NavigationViewModel();
        //FullScreen.Content = new MainInterface();
    }

    private void Image_Source(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cover == 1)
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("---------");
        if (cover == 2)
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("---------");
    }
    private void Change_Image_UP(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cover = cover + 1;
        if (cover > 2)
            cover = 1;
        if (cover == 1)
        {
            this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Pokemorph Island;component/images/cover1.jpg", UriKind.Absolute)));
        }
        else if (cover == 2)
        {
            this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Pokemorph Island;component/images/cover2.png", UriKind.Absolute)));
        }
    }
    private void Change_Image_Down(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cover = cover - 1;
        if (cover < 1)
            cover = 2;
        if (cover == 1)
        {
            this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Pokemorph Island;component/images/cover1.jpg", UriKind.Absolute)));
        }
        else if (cover == 2)
        {
            this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Pokemorph Island;component/images/cover2.png", UriKind.Absolute)));
        }
    }
    private void Patreon_Link(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.patreon.com/user?u=3253293");
    }
}
```

Mainmenu Usercontrol

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="New Game" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Height="76" Background="#338B0000" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe Print" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Command="{Binding CharCreaCommand}" CommandParameter="CharCrea"/>
    <Button Content="Load Game" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}" Margin="10,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Height="76" Background="#338B0000" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe Print" FontSize="24"/>
    <Label Content="Pokémorph Island" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="103,313,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="111" Width="616" Foreground="#CCFF00C5" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Rage Italic" FontSize="80"/>
    <Button Content="Settings" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}" Margin="10,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Height="76" Background="#338B0000" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe Print" FontSize="24"/>
</Grid>
```

The Current MVVM I've been trying to use

```
class NavigationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand MainCommand { get; set; }

    public ICommand CharCreaCommand { get; set; }

    private object selectedViewModel;

    public object SelectedViewModel
    {
        get { return selectedViewModel; }

        set { selectedViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel"); }
    }

    public NavigationViewModel()
    {
        MainCommand = new BaseCommand(OpenMain);

        CharCreaCommand = new BaseCommand(OpenCharCrea);
    }

    private void OpenMain(object obj)
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new MainInterfaceViewModel();
    }

    private void OpenCharCrea(object obj)
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new Character_CreationViewModel();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}

public class BaseCommand : ICommand
{
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private Action<object> _method;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public BaseCommand(Action<object> method)
        : this(method, null)
    {
    }

    public BaseCommand(Action<object> method, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _method = method;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _method.Invoke(parameter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WPF has a notoriously tough learning curve. Partly because the MVVM pattern is used and it requires a certain amount of lateral thinking.
If you're thinking "this is hard" then that's normal. You're not being slow.

You've got a mix of code there. Try and move towards binding everything and away from events.
I would also suggest you use the mvvmlightlibs framework. Right click project in solution explorer, choose manage nuget packages and add the package. Use relaycommand for most icommands. There's also a base viewmodel implements inotifypropertychange you can inherit viewmodels from. Unless you need to serialise them.

One way to do this is to host the usercontrol you intend switching out in a contentcontrol. Bind the content to a property in your viewmodel. You then set that to either of two viewmodels. I'm not sure what to call them, let's say Start and Game. So you'll have a StartView with your initial buttons in it and a GameView with the buttons they need during the game. You then have a startVM and GameVM viewmodels with commands which correspond to your buttons.

I think you nearly have the idea of that in your code but an example template might look like:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:StartVM}">
    <local:Start/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Those have scope. So you can put that in a resources for a window and it's the whole window or a grid and it's just that grid.
You can also put them in a resource dictionary, merge that resource dictionary in app.xaml and it affects everywhere in your app.

You then need your contentcontrol to bind it's content to a property which will give it that gamevm or starvm. You look like you have that. Sort of.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"
```

I've tried to explain all this stuff but I think this brings us to your problem.
You need a command which will set that SelectedViewModel property and what you have is just a method.
Here are some example relaycommands:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn237302.aspx

Your layout also looks a bit odd.
I wouldn't use a dockpanel, I'd suggest just a grid.
Usually I'd expect a toolbar kind of deal to be a top narrow banner and some content underneath it.